# How to reload page when jquery.counter trigger finish.countdown event for multiple instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, jquery-countdown

I am using multiple instance for [jQuery countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) and implement page reload when counter get finished
E.g.

```
$('.countdown').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), 
    finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');

    $this.countdown((finalDate), function(event) {
        var days = event.strftime('%D');
        $(this).find('.days').children('span').html(days);
        $(this).find('.hours').children('span').html(event.strftime('%H'));
        $(this).find('.minutes').children('span').html(event.strftime('%M'));
        $(this).find('.seconds').children('span').html(event.strftime('%S'));
    });
    $(this).on('finish.countdown', function(event){
        /*if(!window.location.hash && !(window.location.hash.indexOf('_loaded') > -1)) {
            window.location = window.location + '#_loaded'; window.location.reload();
        }*/
        //If I put window location reload here it will goes into infinite loop. Also above commented code will reload page twice initially which is also not valid solution.
    });
});
```

Issue: If countdown is already finished (E.g. 00:00:00:00 ) then page reload occur twice when script loaded at first time,

I have used localStorage concept but unable to find exact solution. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had almost this issue with page constantly reloading instantly. 
Try and check if your local time and server time are the same. In my case, the difference was two hours, which was the issue that put the page into constant loop.
Countdown plugin has some notes on timezone awareness: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/timezone-aware.html